# JS: How long does it take to call a function?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, math, callstack

So, I am programming a 2d Javascript physics simulation. The performance is good, but I'm going through making optimizations to make it better. So, because the program works with a lot of physical geometry, I make several Pythagorean Theorem calculations in the program. In all, about five calculations; together, they run about one million times per second. So, I figured it would boost performance if I put that simple Pythagorean theorem code into a new function and called it; after all, that way the browser has less compiling to do. So, I ran the code in Firefox and got.... a 4000000% *increase* in the execution time of that calculation.

How? It's the same code: Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y), so how does adding it as a function slow it down? I assume the reason is that a function takes time just to be called, without executing the code, and that adding that a million of these delays per second slows it down?

That seems rather alarming to me. Would this also apply to predefined js functions? It seems unlikely, and if so, how do they avoid it?

The code used to go like this:

```
function x()
{
    dx=nx-mx;
    dy=ny-my;
    d=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    doStuff(...
}
```

What I tried was this:

```
function x()
{
    dx=nx-mx;
    dy=ny-my;
    d=hypo(dx,dy);
    doStuff(...
}
function hypo(x,y)
{
    return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your function defined outside of the scope that is being ran a million times a second?

Comment: And it's not true that the browser has "less compiling to do" because you put it in a function... it should be about the same, really, especially since compilation is a startup thing. But @alex probably got the reason for your 400% slowdown :)

Comment: @alex Yes, it is defined in the main window.

Comment: It is important to have the exact code you are talking about. Try using http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Note that when you call a function, the browser has to allocate memory for new variables and copy the values into them (i.e. for the parameters of the function). This would no doubt add overhead

Comment: @minitech You're probably right, but it seemed like it would be less since it only has to the one function rather than several equally large calculations?

Comment: @appclay you may be on to something, but I still wonder whether and how predefined functions avoid it?

Comment: Hopefully some mozilla or webkit developers can comment on this one...

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger I've added the pertinent code.

Comment: @j08691 Working on it, but the code is very long and interdependent and it will take some time to set up.

Comment: In the mean time, the firebug profiler tells me that the pythagorean calculation takes 0.001% of the execution time normally, and a whopping 39.7% with the new function. (Oops, I forgot three zeroes from my percentage figure in my post :)

Comment: +1 for **not** putting the code on jsfiddle and posting it here instead, which is the proper way to ask here, and for a well-asked question (after the edit adding code). A jsfiddle link as an additional reference to your post would have been fine, but having the actual code here so it's available to future users who run across it or search for it is the right way to do it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function calls are negligible or even optimizing in pre-compiled languages which JS has never been. Beyond that, a great deal depends on the browser.

They're the death of all performance in interpreted languages which JS has been primarily until fairly recently. Most modern browsers have JIT (Just In Time) compilers which is a huge upgrade from the JS interpreters of the past but I believe function calls to another scope still cost some overhead because JS's call object has to determine what is actually being called and that means marching up and down various scope chains.

So as a general rule: if you care about IE8 and lower and older versions of Chrome and Firefox avoid function calls period. Especially inside loops. For the JIT browsers, I would expect that a function defined inside the other function would be generally beneficial (but I would still test as this is brand new technology for IE9 and relatively new for everybody else).

One other thing to be wary of. If a function is particularly complex, JIT's may not do anything to optimize them.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/closure-compiler-discuss/4B4IcUJ4SUA/OqYWpSklTE4J

But the important thing to understand is that when something is locked and only called inside a context, like a function within a function, it should be easy for a JIT to optimize. Defined outside of a function, it has to determine which definition of that function is being called exactly. It could be in an outer function. It could be global. It could be a property of the window object's constructor's prototype, etc... In a language where functions are first class, meaning their references can be passed around as args the same way you pass data around, you can't really avoid that step outside of your current context.

So try defining hypo inside X to see what happens.

Another couple of general tips from the interpreted age that might still be valuable in JITs:

- The '.' operator as in `someObject.property`, is a process worth caching. It costs overhead as there is an associated call object lookup process every time you use it. I imagine Chrome would not preserve the results of this process since alterations to parent objects or prototypes could alter what it actually references outside of a given context. In your example if x is being used by a loop (likely okay or even helpful if x is defined in the same function as the loop in JITs - murder in an interpreter), I would try assigning Math.sqrt to a var before using it in hypo. Having too many references to stuff outside of the context of your current function might cause some JITs to decide it's not worth the trouble to optimize but that's pure speculation on my part.
- The following is probably the fastest way to loop an array:

> ```
> //assume a giant array called someArray
> var i = someArray.length; //note the property lookup process being cached here
> //'someArray.reverse()' if original order isimportant
> while(i--){
>   //now do stuff with someArray[i];
> }
> ```

note: code block not working here for some reason.

Doing it this way can be helpful because it basically morphs the inc/decrement step and the logical comparison into just the decrement, completely removing the need for a left/right comparison operator. Note that in JS the right side decrement operator means that i gets passed to be evaluated and then decremented before it's used inside the block. `while(0)` evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks; a very nice explanation! Defining the hypo function inside the larger function takes too much time and I would need it in other functions, so it isn't worth it for me. Out of curiosity, though, I did try defining it inside. That solved 97% of the performance problems! It's still inflated, but much better. Do you know how predefined functions avoid this? Thanks again!

Comment: Core JS objects and methods are actually operating on a much lower level. If you try alerting Math.sqrt, for instance (no parens) you'll probably see a function with [NATIVE CODE] or something on the inside. That's actually a call pulling from the browser's pre-compiled run-time environment typically. It can still be helpful to cache those lookups though because you can replace those references to the natively defined methods with whatever you want in JS (not very smart but it lets you do that). Which means JIT's still gotta account for the lookup process.

Comment: Also, if you've still got it all set up, try Hypo defined inline with 'var sqrt = Math.sqrt' right before it and then call sqrt instead inside hypo. I'm curious.

Comment: One last thing: JS has trig functions in its math object if those are any use to you. I would bet good money those would help perf a lot over actually doing the math yourself if it were practical to do so. My geometry is rusty but I believe the Pythagorean theorem is the basis for those.

Comment: I use the trig even more than the sqrt, don't worry. :)

Comment: I've added the performance data with and without caching as a link at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, caching the lookup as suggested by Erik doesn't do much to improve performance on my browser (Chromium, Linux) but seems hurts performance instead: 
http://jsperf.com/inline-metric-distance

```
var optimizedDistance = (function () { 
    var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
    return function (x, y) { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }
})();
```

is *slower* than

```
var unoptimizedDistance = function(x, y) {
    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Even calling an alias is slower

```
var _sqrt = Math.sqrt; // _sqrt is slower than Math.sqrt!
```

But then again, this is not an exact science and real life measurements can still vary.

Nonetheless, I'd go with using `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: Interesting. I will do my own tests in a second.

Comment: Alright. I've tested all the code with and without Math caching. I defined them as globals so that my different functions could access them and then ran it. It appears that except in a few cases, caching was somehow slower.